# Select value out of array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

Ok, so I have this in a JSON array (the output of *retrievedData()*)

```
{
    "device": {
        "01AA02AB141208VV": {
            "$version": -148598935,
            "$timestamp": 1344382016000,
            "serial_number": "01AA02AB141208VV"
        }
    }
}
```

However, I can't seem to select the serial number. I have tried what usually works, but I can't select it. This is assuming we don't already know the "01AA02AB141208VV".

```
$retrieved_data = retrieveData($array['userid'], $array['urls']['transport_url'], $array['access_token']);
$retrieved_data_array = json_decode($retrieved_data, true);
$serial_number = $retrieved_data_array['device'][0]['serial_number'];
```

Am I doing something wrong? I bet it's really simple, but I just cannot figure it out!

Thanks!

Comment: where is the code for `retrieveData` function? Show us the result of `var_dump($retrieved_data_array)`.

Comment: what is $array? , does it matter?

Comment: If you don't already know the serial number, then you have no way of accessing the data without looping through each `device` using a foreach and examining the contents.

Comment: retrieveData is a huge script that just outputs the JSON array. Really not needed, since I gave you its output. $array is also sperate from this and has no effect on it.

Comment: @jprofitt: actually it is an array since `true` was passed as the 2nd argument.

Comment: @cOle2 Ahh missed that! Good call...statement retracted!

Comment: although you provided a the value of `retrievedData()` you should make that clear in your question. else it's hard to understand without scanning the comments ;)

Comment: @Jocelyn That's what I posted at the top of my question.

Comment: Your missing a '}' and the ',' at the end is weird. At the moment it is not valid JSON.

Comment: @Tessmore Sorry, I trimmed out the extra that isn't needed. My bad. It IS valid according to JSONLint in it's entirety.

Comment: Ok assuming you mean the valid version of the JSON! You are trying to access ['device'][0], but there is no '0' key, the key is '01AA02AB141208VV'. If you want to access the first in the list you can use `array_shift()`

Comment: You could loop through the device array and pull out all keys. Would that help? Or are you trying to find the serial number without knowing it? foreach( $retrieved_data_array['device'] as $key => $val )

Comment: will **device** have multiple *version, timestamp, serial_number* thingies? If so, then how do you know which serial number you are looking for? Is it always the first one?

Comment: Ahh, I thought [0] would get the first result no matter what, (new to this JSON stuff). I am always looking for the serial_number of the first key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use key() function to access the keys of the associative array (in this case the '$retrieved_data_array['device']' array:

```
<?php

$data = '{"device": {"01AA02AB141208VV": {"$version": -148598935,"$timestamp": 1344382016000,"serial_number": "01AA02AB141208VV"}}}';

$retrieved_data_array = json_decode($data, true);
$serial_number = key($retrieved_data_array['device']);
reset($retrieved_data_array['device']);

print_r($serial_number);
print_r($retrieved_data_array['device'][$serial_number]);

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it's not really simple.  You're trying to find 42 Main St. when you don't know the city Main St. is located in.  The only way to find the `serial_number` would be to loop over `$retrieved_data_array` with `foreach` until you find the value you want.

Answer (score 1):

This will grab the serial numbers, assuming you have multiple items in the devices array:

```
$keys = array();

foreach( $retrieved_data_array['device'] as $key => $val ){
  $keys[] = $key;
}

$serial = $keys[0];
```

**This can be reduced if you know you only have one item in the array...**

Comment: Now, if there were two, would $keys[1] grab the next?